Why is it true that $\left[\mathbb Q\left( \frac{\sqrt{3 + \sqrt{21}}}{2}, \sqrt{3}i\right): \mathbb Q( \frac{\sqrt{3 + \sqrt{21}}}{2})\right]= 2$
I understand that it must be at least $2$ ($i$ is not in $\mathbb Q \left(\frac{\sqrt{3 + \sqrt{21}}}{2}\right)$. To show that it is actually $2$, shouldn't we prove also that $\sqrt{3} \in \mathbb  Q\left(\frac{\sqrt{3 + \sqrt{21}}}{2}\right)$?

Let $\alpha=\frac{\sqrt{3+\sqrt{21}}}{2}$. Then we have $\sqrt{-3}\notin \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, since every element of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is real.
Therefore the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{-3}$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ has degree at least two.
But we know a polynomial of degree two that has a root in $\sqrt{-3}$: it's $x^2+3$. Hence, the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{-3}$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ has degree exactly two, so $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\sqrt{-3}):\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)]=2$
